# ¿Como hacer un setText en una funcion?

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy usando qt para crear una interfaz, pero desde una funcion deseo modificar un Label.
Este es mi problema

```
void Funcion_uno (ListaBotellas *entrada, ColaBotellas *cola,int tiempo){
    int x = 1;
    while(x == 1){
        m.lock();
        Botella *var1=entrada->getBotella();
        NodoBotellaCola *nueva= new NodoBotellaCola(var1);
        if(cola->full()){
        cout<<"Cola llena"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cola->encolar(nueva);
            cout<<nueva->botella->nombre<<endl;
            ui->txt_actual->setText(); //Esto es lo que deseo poner, pero me dice "use of undeclared identifier 'ui'" 

        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(tiempo*1000));
        m.unlock();
    }
}
```

Quiero aclarar que esta funcion esta dentro de donde se configuran los botones y toda la ui, en el cpp

Comment: Ya tu while True me da miedo, ¿que estas haciendo?, con ese while true estas bloqueando la GUI, por ejemplo intenta cambiar el tamaño de la ventana y veras que la GUI esta congelada. Si tienes una tarea pesada crea un hilo y envia la información mediante señales, por otro lado si quieres colocar un texto debes pasar el texto: `ui->txt_actual->setText("foo");`, quizas el mensaje que señalas es porque no existe el elemento txt_actual, y eso solo lo sabremos si compartes el .ui, o mejor provees un [mcve]

Comment: El while true es mientras busco que otra condicion le pongo, pero resulta ser que esos son hilos entonces necesito mantenerlo en un while para que el hilo siga funcionando.
El txt_actual si existe, de hecho lo compilo para que aparezca, porque si lo intento utilizar en un boton, me funciona, pero en una funcion aparte, no me sirve.

Comment: el objeto `ui` es un miembro privado de la clase, nunca sera accesible desde fuera. lo que debes hacer pasar el objeto de la ventana a la funcion, ademas debes crear un metodo setter: `public: void setText(const QString & text){ui->txt_actual->setText(text);}`

Comment: La ui ya la hice publica, intentare este metodo setter